# Can highlight an expression in mathematica in an expansion?

Tags: series-expansion, syntax-highlighting

I ask mathematica to make an expansion of some expression. Is there a way to ask mathematica to highlight all terms that, say, goes by x^3 since it is really hard to find them? E.g.

```
Expand[(x + y) (x + z) (x + w)]
```

gives

```
w x^2 + x^3 + w x y + x^2 y + w x z + x^2 z + w y z + x y z
```

and the question is how can I highlight or isolate all terms that go as x^3?

Comment: Does `Collect[...,x^3]` do what you're looking for? I will at least group all the x^3 terms together

Comment: Seems to help, indeed. But, it would be great if there was a way to highlight stuff not look line by line..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way could be using a `Style`.

```
Expand[(x + y) (x + z) (x + w)] /. {x^2 ->  
   Style[x^2, Red, Background -> LightBlue]}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
    expr = Expand[(x + y) (x + z) (x + w)];
rule[x_] := x -> Style[x, Background -> Yellow];
```

Then you may apply the rule to the expression as follows

```
expr /. rule[x^3]
```

with the effect

[image]

or

```
expr /. rule[x^2]
```

giving

[image]

but the most simple substitution

```
expr /. rule[x]
```

does not work, since it highlights all terms containing x. But this might be no problem for your aims.

Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

Just an extension to Alexei Boulbitch's answer: if you want to highlight `x`, you can change the function to:

```
Clear[rule];
expr = Expand[(x + y) (x + z) (x + w)];
rule[x_] := {Power[x, y_] :> Power[x, y], 
  x :> Style[x, Background -> Yellow]}
```

[image]